# get values of audited instead of provisional for the same year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data of company where  company number. is their company name year and audit type is given. for each company their is data available of last few years from that data i only want data of latest 3 years and along with this give preference to audited instead of provisional.
e.g.

```
Sr no.  number   Company    year    type          value
0   223 abc 2015    audited         3
1   223 abc 2018    provisional 4
2   223 abc 2019    audited         5
3   223 abc 2019    provisional 6
4   223 abc 2020    audited         7
5   224 def 2017    provisional 8
6   224 def 2016    audited         9
7   224 def 2017    audited         10
8   224 def 2018    audited         11
9   224 def 2019    provisional 12
```

Expected Output

```
number  Company    Year type 
223     abc       2018 provisional
223     abc        2019 audited
223     abc        2020 audited
224     def        2017 audites
224     def        2018 audited
224     def        2019 provisional
```

Comment: i want latest 3 years. Some company have data from 1998 some have data of 2002. few have data of past 2 years few have data of past 25 years. I want each company latest 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html) after assigning a [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) type to your "type", and filtering the years greater or equal to 2017 (here with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)):

```
out = (df
   .assign(type=pd.Categorical(df['type'], ['provisional', 'audited'],
                               ordered=True))
   .query('year >= 2017')
   .groupby(['number', 'Company', 'year'], as_index=False)['type'].max()
)
```

*NB. you could achieve the same with `groupby.min` and keeping the "type" as strings, as `"audited"<"provisional"`.*

Output:

```
   number Company  year         type
0     223     abc  2018  provisional
1     223     abc  2019      audited
2     223     abc  2020      audited
3     224     def  2017      audited
4     224     def  2018      audited
5     224     def  2019  provisional
```